# There is already an object named 'PersonalData' in the database during migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I created a migration:

> Add-Migration InitPersonDataMigration -Project
>   PersonalData.Dal -StartupProject ConsoleApp3 -OutputDir
>   Migrations/PersonalDataMigrations -Context PersonalDataContext

when the database did not exist.

Next, I try to migrate:

> Update-Database -migration 20200323075750_InitPersonDataMigration
>   -Project PersonalData.Dal -StartupProject ConsoleApp3 -Context PersonalDataContext

But...:

> There is already an object named 'PersonalData' in the database

It seems that this table is trying to be created 2 times.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was here:

```
public PersonalDataContext()
{
      Database.EnsureCreated(); //<<---
}
```

First, the regular creation of the database was performed, and then the migration of creating the database was rolled.